# How escape single quote with jQuery Template

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-templates

With jQuery Template I process this string

```
$.tmpl('regionTemplate', {value: key, title: value.name});
```

if value.name have a single quote, example **L'Aquila** jQuery template not rendering string

Comment: Don't know much about jQuery-Templates (only know that it's no longer being developed). Try escaping that single quote like so: \'

Answer (score 0):

```
value.name.replace( "'", "\'" )
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax `$.tmpl('regionTemplate', {value: key, title: value.name});` is incomplete. Are you using appendTo or similar?

```
 $.tmpl('regionTemplate', {value: key, title: value.name}).appendTo( "#myContainer" );
```

See [archived docs](http://web.archive.org/web/20120921051311/http://api.jquery.com/jquery.tmpl/)

You should not need to escape the '. `${title}` in the template will render correctly. (See [this sample](http://borismoore.github.io/jquery-tmpl/demos/step-by-step/0_tmpl-read-only/2_html-tag.html), for example). Otherwise, you need to show your code and template, or create a jsfiddle to show your problem...